# List "copying to tmp table on disk" MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, logging, tmp

Sometimes the MySQL database we use generates files on the `/tmp` disk to temporary store results when performing a query.

On StackOverflow there are a lot of posts on how to disable this behavior or speed it up by for instance using a RAM disk.

I'm looking however for an elegant way to save the queries that have generated such files since I believe most of these queries can be optimized.

Is there a way to log these queries?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given such queries usually take a long time, we can assume these are all *slow queries*. We can [log slow queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html) using the `slow_query_log_file` and `slow_query_log` variables:

```
-- set the log file location
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log_file = '/path/to/slow_log_file.log';
-- turn on slow query logging
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = ON;
```

Make sure that the `mysql` user (or the user than runs the MySQL daemon) has write access rights to the directory and file.